# FIRDatabase not found

Tags: database, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add the **Firebase Realtime Database** feature in my application but I realised I had not put it in my `pod file`.

So that's what I did, I added `'Firebase/Database'` and ran `pod update` and went back into my workspace and I still cannot access `FIRDatabase`.

Here is what my `podfile` looks like:

```
target 'myproject' do
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth
pod 'Firebase/Database'
end
```

Thank you to anybody that replies it, is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean cant access `FIRDatabase` ? Does the pods install correctly w/o errors? Does it say `No such module found` when you try to import **FIRDatabase**.. ? Did you import `Firebase` and `FirebaseDatabase` both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you open the cocoapod generated file `.xcworkspace` or the one you already had `.xcodeproj`? Try to use `Swift 3` and `Xcode 8`

Thats the way you should do it inside the `podfile`:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

    target 'YourTargetName' do
      pod "Firebase"
      pod 'Firebase/Database'
    end
```

Comment: Yep, I double checked to make sure I was using the generated file.

Comment: Are you using Swift 3 and Xcode 8? And did you imported Firebase inside your controller?

Comment: xCode 8 did the trick, for some reason I wasn't using it. Thank you so much! You don't understand how much I appreciate people like you. Have a great day.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Happy coding :)

Comment: Adding pod "Firebase" actually solved my problem. Just adding pod 'Firebase/Database' doesn't help XCode recognize framework.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by adding `import FirebaseDatabase`

Answer (score 1):

Firebase updates the new syntax to this.

```
Database.database().reference()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this

```
target 'myproject' do
pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
end
```

Comment: I code this error `Invailed Podfile file; syntax error, unexpected tIdentifer, expecting keyword_end` My podile looks the same as yours.

Comment: `target project do

  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'
  pod ‘Firebase/Core’
  pod ‘Firebase/Database’
  pod ‘Firebase/Auth’ 
 
end`

Comment: Fixed the syntax error, however FIRDatabase still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

There's 3 possible things that could have gone wrong one being that you forgot to export Firebase in your Conroller so adding `import Firebase` would do the trick or you just simply need to build the project using `Command B` in order to make the pos recognisable and refresh your project. Finally if that doesn't work make sure you have .xcworkspace and not .xcodeproj

Comment: Firebase is imported, and I can use FIRAuth. But FIRDatabase isn't working.

Comment: did you try command B to rebuild the project, if you did does using FIRDatabase still not work?

Comment: Correct, it still doesn't work `Use of unresolved identifier FIRDatabase`

Comment: Can you give me a sample of the code and how your trying to implement FIRDatase I think I know what your doing wrong

Comment: `var rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()` and it simple doesn't know what FIRDatabase is.